# I keep receiving this error (Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found:)

Tags: java, websphere, servlet-3.0

I trying to create a simple websphere project, but I keep getting an error. I am not sure where I'm going wrong though. I have googled similar questions such as myself but none seem to work for me, as I keep getting the same error.

I have tried to solve the problem in various ways, as well as adding a web.xml file that was missing, but still seems not to work and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegisterServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegisterServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


        String FNAME = request.getParameter("FNAME");
        String LNAME = request.getParameter("LNAME");
        String MSISDN = request.getParameter("MSISDN");
        String AMB = request.getParameter("AMB");
        Connection connection = null;


        try {

            connection =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ussd","root","root1215"); 
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO USERDETAILS (FNAME, LNAME, MSISDN, AMB) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            ps.setString(1, FNAME);
            ps.setString(2, LNAME);
            ps.setString(3, MSISDN);
            ps.setString(4, AMB);;


            int i = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0)
                System.out.println("You are successfully registered...");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(connection !=null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}

//**************** web.xml code********************


<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>RegisterServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.web.servlet.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>



</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post the full URL you are using when you try to hit the servlet?

Comment: You are using annotations, so you dont need `web.xml`, especially outdated one. If you want use web.xml it should be 3.1 version, like this `<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">`. Also which version of WebSphere are you using? Liberty or traditional?

Comment: Also, check your server logs (especially SystemOut.log) to see if the application is actually starting successfully - with a 404, you could be hitting the right location, but it doesn't matter if the app is dead.